# Как в bootstrap 4 двигать столбцы?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В бутстрапе 4 отключили push и pull , читал документацию , написано что нужно использовать offset или order, но ни то ни другое не работает, единственное что нашел это выравнивание колонок по центру через mx-auto , еще можно использовать flex, но там при переходе к мобильной версии сворачивается не так как при использовании колонок, подскажите как именно колонки можно передвинуть , нужно подвинуть колонки с классом col-xl

**Решение найдено , offset передвигает колонки, возможно в первый раз была опечатка в коде**

Comment: приложите пример, offset должен работать

Comment: офсет действительно заработал , странно я его писал и не работало , возможно где то ошибся